# jQuery - Increase integer by using arrays content as the variable name

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, integer

Okay. This might be a little bit difficult to explain. Let's just say I have three variables in **JavaScript**

```
window.seconds = 0;
window.minutes = 0;
window.hours   = 0;
```

and also three anchor tags in **HTML**

```
<a id='seconds_plus' href=''>Increase seconds</a><br>
<a id='minutes_plus' href=''>Increase minutes</a><br>
<a id='hours_plus'   href=''>Increase hours</a><br>
```

Each time a anchor is clicked, the integer of the variable will increase by 1. Now see, I am a lazy person and don't want to write 3 same .click() functions. That is why I came up with a single .click() function on which I have a problem on.

```
$("#hours_plus, #minutes_plus, #seconds_plus").click(function () {
    var increase = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    increase[0]++; // <-----
});
```

Is there a way this could be possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change

```
 increase[0]++
```

to

```
window[increase[0]]++
```

Comment: In addition, I would use a distinct attribute, like `<a id='seconds_plus' data-type="seconds" ` then you'd use `var increase = $(this).data('type');` instead of splitting the id.